# Looping and operating between Sets/Lists

Tags: java, set, iteration

I've had a hard time coming up with a name for this post.
Basically, I have two sets: let's call it `A` and `B`.

I want to do the following (`\` stands for except):

```
C = A\B
loop through C;
D = B\A
loop through D;
loop through B;
```

My first successful attempt was:

```
// B and A are lists

List<T> C = new LinkedList<>(A);
C.removeAll(B);
for (T other : C)
    operationX(other);

List<T> D = new LinkedList<>(B);
D.removeAll(A);
for (T other : D)
    operationY(other);

for (T other : B)
    operationZ(other);
```

But this seems too slow. This function is supposed to be called hundreds of times per second and the sets can contain hundreds of objects.

What would an efficient way of achieving this look like?

Comment: Did you actually try using sets?

Comment: LinkedList is the slowest possible collection. And there is no need to make any copy here. I would also test with using a Stream iterating over the first set and filtering out the elements that are part of the second set. And I would compare that with your approach, but using a HashSet or an ArrayList. Also, of course, if the collections never change, you should store the two differences and reuse them.

Comment: @JBNizet They keep changing of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create `C` at all if you just plan to iterate through it. You can simply filter out every element in `A` that is contained in `B` and then call `operationX` on each filtered element:

```
Set<T> bSet = new HashSet<>(B);

A.stream()
 .filter(a -> !bSet.contains(a))
 .forEach(this::operationX);
```

---

Assuming that there can be duplicate elements inside `B` and `operationY` needs to be called for all duplicates, then we can use the following:

```
Set<T> aSet = new HashSet<>(A);

B.stream()
 .filter(b -> !aSet.contains(b))
 .forEach(this::operationY);

B.forEach(this::operationZ);
```

If `operationY` only needs to be called once for each element in `B` even if duplicates exist, then I recommend using the code below instead:

```
bSet.removeAll(A);
bSet.forEach(this::operationY);
B.forEach(this::operationZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

To compute C=A\B you can first build a HashSet from B and then iterate over A and add all elements to an initially empty set C, which are not in the hash set.

Also, if you often iterate over a large list, you should use ArrayList instead of LinkedList if possible because iterating over large linked lists is really slow due to the many cache misses that occur.